# Dealing with drunken guy harassing us over anti-vaxxer and conspiracy theories, and cops won't do a thing?

Tags: medical, harassment, missouri, misconduct

We're in the U.S, and are a couple who are 37/F and 39/M. We live in a suburb of Kansas City, MO.

Recently me and my fiance have had a drunken guy kept coming to our house harassing us and shouting anti-mask arguments - he's come wearing a bikini and claiming:

> Joe Biden is a clinically obese manwhore who's supporing the Great Reset.

> There's photos of Justin Trudeau wearing his wife's bikini going around, you've got to see them online; ewwww, sick.... Trudeau in a white bikini.

> Joe Biden, Boris Johnson, Justin Trudeau and Bill Gates just want to get The Great Reset in operation, give us all digital IDs, surveil us and effectively want to treat us like pets.

He's advised us not to get a vaccination too, claiming it's a conspiracy theory Bill Gates has put across and claims:

> The Johnson and Johnson vaccine is a means to control the population and there's a gay agenda with this COVID vaccine. Remember the days of gay panic in comics? Well, some of the COVID vaccine is gay panic part 2.

He's also been spreading claims like:

> Attempts to get rid of cash is just government control and big brother. Trump wouldn't have done this.

He's done this 8 times a week, we've got the cops involved but they claim it's not something they want to deal with. This has gone on constantly since March 2020, just before the pandemic.

This guy's constantly showing up morning, noon and night and my fiance has no idea how to deal with it.

The guy is in his mid-20s (so around 25/26), looks unshaven and rough, and he apparently lives over the state line in Kansas and crosses from the Kansas side of Kansas City into Missouri here in Kansas City and often shows up in our neighborhood. He doesn't live here and just shows up on people's doors offering to do odd jobs for cash.

He's also constantly kept bringing us snacks - Lay's crisps, candy bars, Diet Coke bottles whenever he comes, and my fiance's foolishly paid him $100 for the huge box of them in attempt to get rid of him.

The guy's shown up drunk on three or four occasions.

When he does show up, he's always been wearing a bikini, or bikini and a denim skirt, no matter what the weather, sometimes even a tiny Adidas sports bra crop-top and denim skirt.

We've contacted the police several times but they don't consider it as something worth dealing with, saying:

> It's not a priority issue, a guy spreading anti-vax and anti-mask conspiracy theories or doing odd jobs for cash, even if he comes several times a week. FFS, he's hardly a Capitol rioter or a nutjob BLM supporter.

Police won't do a thing, but this guy keeps targeting our house bringing snacks and ranting about Great Reset conspiracy theory, what can we do legally to stop him, get an attorney, or could this end up in a court of law with a grand jury?

Comment: Are you interested in taking this into your own hands and the extent you legally can?

Comment: A lot of the details here are not legally relevant.  Given his rights to free speech and expression, the possibility of any legal action won't be related to what he says (no threats of violence, etc) or what he wears (no indecent exposure).  Where he lives shouldn't matter, either.  You might get more attention to the question if you make it more concise and focused.

Answer (score 5):

The Missouri trespass law is [here](https://revisor.mo.gov/main/OneSection.aspx?section=569.140). The police will not detain a person for expressing himself, even repeatedly, though a court order to stay away would change things. The law says

> A person does not commit the offense of trespass in the first degree
> by entering or remaining upon real property unless the real property
> is fenced or otherwise enclosed in a manner designed to exclude
> intruders or as to which notice against trespass is given by:
>
> (1)  Actual communication to the actor; or
>
> (2)  Posting in a manner reasonably likely to come to the attention
> of intruders.

You can also use [purple paint markers](https://revisor.mo.gov/main/OneSection.aspx?section=569.145&bid=29574).

There is also a [law against stalking](https://www.revisor.mo.gov/main/OneSection.aspx?section=565.225&bid=34708&hl=) which prohibits unwanted communication that may be threatening, intimidating, frightening or causes emotional distress to another person. However, you need to [petition the courts](https://www.courts.mo.gov/page.jsp?id=5054) for an order of protection. If granted, violating the order would be a felony, and more likely to get the attention of the police. Getting an attorney is the simplest immediate solution, since I expect that purple paint won't mean much to him.